# SQL Server Licensing for QA Machines

Tags: sql-server, ssis, licensing

I'm currently working on some infrastructure costing, and I'm having a bit of trouble finding the best solution for SQL Server licensing for QA servers.

We're developing an ETL solution using SSIS. Our solution doesn't have a database per se, but is utilizing SSIS to run validation and transformation on text files in flight. Because we need testers to be able to test in isolation (i.e. each needs to test on their own server), we want to set up virtual machines with the packages installed to their own SQL Server instances.

The problem I'm running into is that there doesn't seem to be a good licensing solution for this scenario. Devs can use Developer Edition through their MSDN licenses, but for QA it looks like we'll actually need full Enterprise Edition licenses (we're using SSIS functionality not available in Standard).

Is there a SKU I'm missing that addresses this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [licensing advice is off-topic on Stack Overflow.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) You may be able to get help on [Programmers Stack Exchange, but **read their faq carefully** before proceeding.](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7265/when-is-a-software-licensing-question-on-topic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK you can use dev editions for QA as long as it is internal and the DB is not accessed from the internet but only intranet

From the [MS site](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/editions.aspx)

> Developer Edition is designed to
>   enable developers to build any type of
>   application on top of SQL Server 2005.
>   It includes all the functionality of
>   Enterprise Edition (win32, x64, IA64)
>   but with a special **development** and
>   **test license** agreement that prohibits production deployment.

What do you mean when you say "we are using SSIS functionality not available in standard edition?"

Comment: We're using the raw file source, which as far as I know is only available in Enterprise.

Comment: If it is available in enterprise it is also available in Dev since the two are equal except for the license

Comment: Yes, developer edition suits my needs, but not Standard. Thanks for the info.